# How to get Stmt class object from Expr object in Clang

Tags: c, clang, llvm, instrumentation

I am writing a clang plugin for inserting assertions in a C code. I have implemented a class for visiting each unary operator and check if it is a pointer dereference. If it is, I would like to insert an NULL pointer assertion check for it. But I am stuck as I cannot figure out how to get the Stmt object containing the Expr object in Clang.

This is my code which instruments the assertion but at a completely wrong location (ie just after the pointer dereference. I would like to do it just before the statement containing the dereference.

```
bool MyRecursiveASTVisitor::VisitUnaryOperator(UnaryOperator *E){
    if (E->getOpcode() == UO_Deref ){
        Expr *e1 = E->getSubExpr();
        SourceLocation SL = E->getLocEnd();
        Rewrite.InsertText(SL, "assert(", true, true);
        Rewrite.InsertText(SL, Rewrite.ConvertToString(e1), true, true);
        Rewrite.InsertText(SL, " != NULL);", true, true);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `ASTContext::getParents`?

You can also build partial parent maps with the `ParentMap` class.

Comment: How can I get the ASTContext object in this case? I am trying to make the Context a member of my class, but it says that the = operator is private so I cannot assign any value to a variable of type ASTContext.

Comment: @anirudh: use a constant reference to `ASTContext`

Comment: @anirudh: also, you can get a `ASTContext` reference from a bunch of places like `TranslationUnitDecl`, `Sema`, etc. Grep for `getASTContext` in the clang source tree

Comment: `getParents` return all the ancestors. Say, the statement is `a = b;`, I'm in the visitor method of binary operator `=`, I want to know it's parent statement, which is `a = b;`, how can I do that?