# How to instrument a statement just before another statement using clang

Tags: clang, llvm, instrumentation

I have to instrument certain statements in clang by adding a statement just before it. I have a pointer to an Expr object using which I need to insert another statement just before the statement containing it. Right now I am using a hacky approach which just moves back the SourceLocation pointer till I see a ; or } or {. But this does not work for all cases. eg when I try to instrument a for statement, it fails. Is there any class in clang which provides a method to do this in a more cleaner way?

EDIT: Here is snippet of my code. I need to insert an assert just before the statement containing a pointer dereference.

```
bool MyRecursiveASTVisitor::VisitUnaryOperator(UnaryOperator *E){
    if (E->getOpcode() == UO_Deref ){
        Expr *e1 = E->getSubExpr();
        SourceLocation SL = E->getLocStart();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you using clang plugin, LibTooling, of libclang?

Comment: I am using LibTooling, i think. I used a starter code for instrumentation so I am not completely sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`getSourceRange()`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Decl.html#af32959df6a722f5089bbdd3dd88ea9bd) on the statement which returns [`SourceRange`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceRange.html) SourceRange Class has `getBegin()` which will return [`SourceLocation`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceLocation.html).

you can checkout https://github.com/eschulte/clang-mutate and see an example there...

**EDIT**:

In order to extract Expr out of Stmt you can checkout this SO question [How to get Stmt class object from Expr object in Clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868994/how-to-get-stmt-class-object-from-expr-object-in-clang?rq=1)

Comment: I do not have the Stmt pointer though, all I have got is the pointer to the Expr inside the statement. Is there a way to go up to the Stmt pointer using the Expr pointer?

Comment: @anirudh -  Can you show snippet of your code... I am not sure I understand what you have